# Justify large text file

Tags: c#, text, memory-management

I got an assignment in C# which's correctness will be evaluated by a program. I should create a program that gets an input text file and creates an output text file where all the text is justified by some rules. Third parameter is maximum text width.
These are the rules:

- Only '\n', '\t', ' ' are considered white-space characters ('\r' won't appear anywhere)
- A word is any sequence of non-whitespace characters surrounded by at least one whitespace character (or beginning/end of file) on both sides.
- An empty line, a line with only whitespace characters or a sequence of such lines are paragraph delimiters. Each paragraph is formatted seperately and output paragraphs are always delimited by a single empty line. Last line of the paragraph must be terminated with a line break but with no empty line following
- Paragraph should contain as many words as possible (while maintaining their order ofc) without exceeding the maximum text width. All words must be seperated by at least one space. If there is still some empty space remaining to achieve the maximum text width, it is distributed among the word gaps by adding space characters. If the extra spaces cannot be distributed uniformly, they should be added fromt the left. Final line of each paragraph should be aligned to the left (all words separated by exactly one space)
- No whitespace character between the last character of the last word on each line and break character.
- If there is a word with more characters than the maximum text width, it should be printed out by itself on a single line. If a line contains only one word, this word should be aligned to the left.

Now we do not know if the text file is very large or not. We are not assured that even a single line could fit into memory. How should this be done? I have tried something but the code is horrible it is not even worth showing. I passed several tests (by the evaluating program) but I fail by exceeding memory limit in the rest. I am not necessarily asking for code but simple pseudo code could help.

(What I have tried simply: I tried reading the input file character by character and counting what I have so far. I was saving what I have read so far in a string which would be the line in the output file and I guess this is a wrong approach.)

Comment: You need to know "what fits into memory" as a size.  This can be your maximum read buffer and then you can do your word/line work from here.  You can also do fun things like memory mapping a file so that the OS takes care of paging for you, though I don't know if this is what the teacher wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave a little bit for research since this is an assignment...

I would use an approach like this, which reads data in chunks into a buffer of pre-defined size (a size smaller than the memory limit):

```
private void ReadInChunks()
{
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Directory\my-file.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        int offset = 0;

        while (fs.Read(buffer, offset, bufferSize) > 0)
        {
            // do stuff with buffer

            offset += bufferSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if the Maximum Width will be larger than the buffer? How will I know where to add more spaces and where not? I cant really get my head around this assignment. Should I write the buffer out in a file and then go through it and fix it?

Comment: @ThePopa611 - In the rules you list, it doesn't specify how much memory you get or how many characters fit on a line.  A line of text on a page would typically take up a trivial amount of memory by modern computing standards... Even if you have a long line of input (thousands of unformatted characters with no line break), I would have to assume that you can fit more than a line of output (at least enough characters to fill the width of a page) into the available memory.  You don't have to read the whole line of input, you just need to read at least enough characters to create a line of output.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I have tried. I did a while cycle where I would read character by character until the end of file and used a counter to see if there should be still more characters in the output line. I detected words (string word += character) and with a whitespace character I saved that word to a string that would represent the output line. If the counter == maximum width, then add more spaces in output line if necessary and write it to a file. Isn't this kind of the way you mean it?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/ - read this article to learn why that approach uses so much memory. The approach I suggested or using the StringBuilder class to create the output string should both work better for you. @ThePopa611